# #SQL - Compare different tables and create a new table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have 4 tables with various columns where ID being the common value in all 4 tables. There is a column called EventDate in all 4 tables but with different values or NULL values for the same ID. The new table should have only ID and EventDate.

I would like to compare all the 4 tables based on the EventDate (ie) if two tables have the same date, it should insert the min date into the new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to combine all and take Minimum date for every ID

```
SELECT ID, MIN(EventDate) AS MIN_DTE INTO NEW_TABLE FROM (
SELECT ID, EventDate from TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, EventDate from TABLE2
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, EventDate from TABLE3
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, EventDate from TABLE4
)A
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: This works. Can I union based on a condition, like if the two table having the same ID with different Eventdate can I choose a minimum of the two?

Comment: If I understood correctly, the above was doing the same thing which you are asking in the comment.